# Creating history of comment field in database table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in an Oracle database that has a comment field in it. I'll call this the CLIENT_INFO table.

I'm trying to create a new table called CLIENT_COMMENTS. It would have time stamped comments that are applicable to a particular client. Instead of having just one comment field,  I'd have a list of comments about the client.

I also have a history table that keeps track of all changes to the CLIENT_INFO table, I'll call this HIS_CLIENT_INFO.

Using the history table, I can create a view of the client's comments as they change over time like this:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, HIS_TIME, COMMENT FROM HIS_CLIENT_INFO ORDER BY CLIENT_ID;
```

The results will be something like this:

```
client_id | his_time             | comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1 | Mar-5-2014, 10:14 AM | Client is thirsty.
        1 | Mar-5-2014, 10:17 AM | Client is thirsty. Also he is hungry.
        2 | Mar-5-2014, 10:13 AM | This client is nice.
        2 | Mar-5-2014, 10:14 AM | This client is nice. He has a cool car.
```

Notice how each time a client's comment is updated or changed, the history results show the new text appended to the old text.

I'm trying to create a table like this:

```
client_id | his_time             | comment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1 | Mar-5-2014, 10:14 AM | Client is thirsty.
        1 | Mar-5-2014, 10:17 AM | Also he is hungry.
        2 | Mar-5-2014, 10:13 AM | This client is nice.
        2 | Mar-5-2014, 10:14 AM | He has a cool car.
```

Here I only have the update to the comment. This new table effectively represents the comment that was entered at that time.

I'm not worried about there being parts of comments deleted, they should only have new text appended to them.

Is there a way to generate this kind of table in SQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lag()` analytic function to peek back at the previous comment for a client, and compare that with the current row to decide whether this is an appended version of the previous one. (It isn't clear if a commend can be entirely replaced or is always appended). And if it has been, use `substr()` to remove the previous comment from the current one.

```
select client_id, his_time,
  trim(case when lag_comment_text is null then
      comment_text
    when comment_text like lag_comment_text || '%' then
      substr(comment_text, length(lag_comment_text) + 1)
    else
      comment_text
    end) as new_comment_text
from (
  select client_id, his_time, comment_text, lag(comment_text)
      over (partition by client_id order by his_time) as lag_comment_text
  from his_client_info
);

 CLIENT_ID HIS_TIME              NEW_COMMENT_TEXT                        
---------- --------------------- ----------------------------------------
         1 Mar-05-2014, 10:14 AM Client is thirsty.                       
         1 Mar-05-2014, 10:17 AM Also he is hungry.                       
         2 Mar-05-2014, 10:13 AM This client is nice.                     
         2 Mar-05-2014, 10:14 AM He has a cool car.
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c0e3/1).

You can use that as a `create table ... as select` (CTAS), or as a view, or whatever.

Comment: I got a second late in posting the same answer. Although your method is more robust in checking for the first part of the string, you could also fulfill OP's criteria just by doing a `TRIM(REPLACE(comment_text, lag_comment_text))` No need to check for null in that case.

Comment: True, but checking it was at the start of the string seemed important, in case the same comment has been used multiple times. (Also I guess it doesn't really need a separate `when` just for null, it could be combined, but I thought it might be clearer split out explicitly).

Comment: Agreed. Always better to be safe in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
with tmp as (
  select row_number() over (partition by client_id order by his_time) rn,
      client_id cid, his_time ht, tcomment comm
    from his_client_info),
r(rn, cid, ht, comm, prior_rn, prior_cid) as (
  select rn, cid, ht, comm, null prior_rn, null prior_cid from tmp where rn=1
  union all
  select tmp.rn, tmp.cid, tmp.ht, trim(replace(tmp.comm, r.comm)), tmp.rn, tmp.ht 
    from tmp join r on tmp.cid = r.cid and tmp.rn = r.rn + 1)
select cid client_id, to_char(ht, 'mm-dd hh24:mi') his_time, 
    comm "comment" 
  from r order by cid, ht
```

Results:

```
client_id  his_time     comment
---------  -----------  -------------------
        1  03-05 10:14  Client is thirsty.
        1  03-05 10:17  Also he is hungry.
        2  03-05 10:13  This client is nice.
        2  03-05 10:14  He has a cool car.
```

When you add third row for client 1 with comment *"Also he is hungry. Also he is ill."* you get only last part.

Comment: [This doesn't quite work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e997c/1) if the third comment is "Client is thirsty. Also he is hungry. Also he is ill", i.e. if the third statement is appended to the previous comment, which I think is what the OP is saying happens. But you can just [track the previous complete comment too](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e997c/2).

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes. Thank you. This solution just operates on previously eliminated parts of comments, that's why I added it. 
From exaples given it was not obvious what should be done in this situation.